# Show the top n 404 requests in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to show the top n requests from an apache access.log, that resulted in a 404 in Kibana. The problem is, that the `request`-field is splitted into path tokens of the complete request, so for example if `./img/flags/us.png` would result in a 404 my table would show `flags` and `img` and so on.

Is there a way to fix that in Kibana or does ES need a mapping for that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your current mapping look like?  And yes, you will need to have `"index": "not_analyzed"` on your mapping for that field.

Comment: i used the default mapping from logstash (ie `request: {type:string}` ). After deleting the index and setting the field to `not_analyzed` it is working now.. Thanks! I would give you the credits if you write an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `"index": "not_analyzed"` on the mapping for the `request` field.